# Java JTextArea Printing

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextarea

I'm trying to print the contents of a JTextArea, using the default font (plain text). I'm literally just doing:

```
this.printTextArea.print()
```

Where printTextArea is a JTextArea. The last line is usually missing when I print, but it shows if I view the contents of the JTextArea or print to PDFCreator.

What could be the problem? I thought it might be something to do with unflushed buffers, but I don't really have any control over what the print() method does.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: it is so interesting i think i can be related with carrage and linefeed characters the print method may read line by line but the last line may not finishing with new line so it does not print can you try adding a new line after the  textarea content

Comment: Do you know if the method takes a JComponent object or a String object?

Comment: It could also have to do with wrong boundary calculation due to font or inner margin. `setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20))` should have some telling effect. (The unprinted border effects the margins.)

Comment: First of all, you should share your code, so we can see other issues there. 

Nonetheless, is this code in try-catch block? Is there any exception?

Comment: An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem might be instructive.

Comment: @daemon: I tried adding newlines but the problem persisted. I also tried Joop Eggen's suggestion but it didn't reveal much.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. If yu cal print ust after setText() or appent() and view isn't ready yet and has old size.

Call the print inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.